# Create a table with relationships SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know how relationships between tables are created.

I intend that when a new row is added to table1 that row is also created in table 2, how can I do this?

```
 Table1
 ID_Orders   ID_Line   Orders   Clients
    1          2        A       ABC
    2          2        B       ABC

 Table2
 ID_Orders   ID_Line   Product
    1          2        A       
    2          2        B
```

I tried to use the foreign key relationship, but it is not working.

```
CREATE TABLE Table2(
 ID_Orders   int ,
 ID_Line   int,
 Product text,
 FOREIGN KEY(ID_Orders) REFERENCES Table1(ID_Orders),
 FOREIGN KEY(ID_Line) REFERENCES Table1(ID_Line)
 );
```

Comment: Creating a row in a table when one is inserted into another doesn't have anything to do with relationships; it's just 2 `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Also, why are you using `text`? It's been deprecated for 16 years now; you should have started using `varchar(MAX)` years ago.

Comment: You might want to read about [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers)

Comment: I use varchar is just an example  :)

Comment: Is Table 2 a real table anyway? Could also be just a view of Table2, if Product and Orders is the same thing with different names?

Comment: _that row is also created in table 2_ That does not happen automatically. You must write code to do that. Relationships are only **controlled or enforced** via constraints. If you want to have a discussion about database design, it helps to use actual entity (i.e., table) names so everyone can understand your model. Generic names like "table1" are not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's the most lazy way but it worked :) thanks

**SQL Management Studio**
**Select Script... Create to... New Query Window.**

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is not a standard relationship between two tables.  Those relationships are described using foreign key relationships.  But you want "automatic" updates.

The simplest method is to use a view:

```
create view table2 as
    select ID_Orders, ID_Line, Orders as Product
    from table1;
```

A variant on this is a *materialized view*, which would materialize the data, so queries might be faster (well, probably not in this case, but possibly if the query were more complicated).

An alternative is to have a *bona fide* `table2` and using an `insert` (and perhaps `update` and `delete` triggers as well) on `table1`.  When a row is inserted into `table1` then the trigger can copy data to `table2`.

All that said, it is a bad practice to store the same data in multiple places.  Sometimes, it can be an important optimization.  But from what you describe, you don't need two tables.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but where the products are stored